# Screen brightness goes down to almost 0 when charger is plugged

Tags: brightness

Acer Aspire-A515-45
Ubuntu 22.04

Same problem as this question: [Screen brightness goes to 10-15% when charger plugs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1395605/screen-brightness-goes-to-10-15-when-charger-plugs/1395642?noredirect=1#comment2492204_1395642)

The solution brought doesn't work for me. I did all steps without it working.
Moreover changing settings with the command:

> gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim false

doesn't seem to change a thing.

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but please edit your question, take out the answer and post it as a separate answer below, so you can mark this issue as "answered".

Comment: To be clear use the Answer Your Own Question button at the bottom of the question. Put the info for the question that is the answer part and place it there, remove it from the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

By modifying file /etc/default/grub, this line:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

To this line:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"

Then running command `sudo update-grub` and rebooting